# Zip files is not getting created

Tags: php, html, forms, zip

I am trying to add files into a zip by sending the file names from a HTML form.
The HTML code is

```
<form action="act.php" method="POST">
<input type="checkbox" name="send1" value="filename1.extension">
<input type="checkbox" name="send1" value="filename2.extension">
</form>
```

The PHP

I tried in two ways
Method 1:

```
$zipfilename="abcd.zip";
$zip= new ZipArchive();
$zip->open($zipfilename, ZipArchive::CREATE);
foreach($_POST['send1'] as $filename)
{
$zip->addFile($filename);
}
$zip->close();
```

Method 2:

```
$zipfilename="abcd.zip";
$filestozip=array();
foreach($_POST['send1'] as $filename)
{
$filestozip[]=$filename;
}

$zip= new ZipArchive();
$zip->open($zipfilename, ZipArchive::CREATE);

foreach($filestozip as $filename2)
{
$zip->addFile($filename2);}
}

$zip->close();
```

But the Zip File is not getting created. I tried to check the Zip syntax with static code for $filetozip as

```
$filestozip[0]="filename1.extension";
$filestozip[0]="filename1.extension";
```

It worked. But when the data is from another HTML page dynamically it does not work. What is the error in my code?

Comment: Please indent your code properly

Comment: Check your idents, in method 2 these seems to be a mismath with one } too many

Comment: Why would method 2 be needed?

Comment: @MihaiStancu: Just tried as an alternate.

Comment: I understand that, but the only reason I'd separate the two actions (collecting & feeding data) is if I could either collect or feed bulk. As in $zip->addMultipleFiles($array). And I have separated them on some occasions when both collection and feeding took long and intermixing them took even longer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the problem. There is no problem in my logic.

```
$zip->addFile($filename);
```

As I said previous the data for the $filename variable is received from a HTML for in which any spaces are replaced by %20 intentionally by me. The reason for such replacement is to enable links to the file using the data. But if the space is replaced by %20 zipArchive::addFile() does not add the zip file which ultimately result in Zip creation fail.

Answer (score 0):

You're using ZipArchive::addFile($file) which expects those files to exists somewhere on the server or if supported protocols are used, somewhere on another server.

Are those files accessible/readable to your script? Is it a full path you're using or a relative one?

If you would use file_get_contents($filename); would it output the expected data?

You should always check file_exists before using addFile().

Comment: Those files exist in the server and obviously reachable. And it is the relative path too. Example: addFile(directory1/directory2/filename.extension).

Comment: And I just tested it with the following syntax,

echo "$filestozip[0]";

Comment: That doesn't output the *contents* of the file, just the file name. But if you're sure files are accessible for read and archive is accessible for write it's ok.

Comment: I've only used this function with the first and the second parameter (local name). Maybe that's the problem.